# iis and asp.net config

Tags: iis, asp.net

ok so im trying to add asp.net feature on windows 7 i tried to turn it on using turn windows features on or off but it fails every time

so i download web platform installer and try it that way and it fails also

next i uninstall .net framework 4 restart again! and reinstall it and try again the previous steps but it fails the same

i need this installed so i can view it on iis7

anyone know what i can do with this to get it working ive searched and searched and everything fails

i get this error on the web platform installer Failed with 0x80070643 – Fatal Error during installation

please help i cant do my work with out it working :(

also tried to register asp.net with iis. So install iis using the features and then execute the command "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" with the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

but got this error

aspnet_regiis.exe -i is not recognised as and internal or external sommand operable program or batch file???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a thread](http://forums.iis.net/p/1148533/1865891.aspx) with similar symptoms over on the IIS.net forums. Basically, the 2 things to try are:

1. Remove the "Windows Process Activation Service" and IIS features from the computer, then reinstall them.
2. Do an "OS Repair" installation of windows, due to the component based services catalog being corrupt. An OS Repair install would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I do not supply the full correct path to the utility [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846544/how-to-fix-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-module-managedpip/10541165#10541165).

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -I

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```